# IBM MQ - how to connect to Queue manager with multiple connections names ( one is fail over)

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am quite new to IBM MQ's. Mine is a multi-instance queue manager.

One instance is like fail-over.

How can I connect to them even if one of is down.

I am not sure whether my terminology is right or not?

I am trying to connect using below example now

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-samples/master/gettingStarted/jms/JmsPutGet.java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of populating `WMQ_HOST_NAME` and `WMQ_PORT` populate `WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST` with a comma separated list that is in the format `host1(port1),host2(port2)`. IBM MQ will attempt to connect to host1 first and if it fails it will attempt host2 during the initial connection attempt.

If you want the client to reconnect on failure you will need to enable mq auto reconnect like this:

```
cf.setClientReconnectOptions(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
cf.setClientReconnectTimeout(1800); // how long in seconds to continue to attempt reconnection before failing
```

Comment: Thank you that helps. For reconnect option, I have to change it to        MQConnectionFactory cf = (MQConnectionFactory) ff.createQueueConnectionFactory();     from    JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory(); How to test whether it is really reconnecting? can we bring one instance down from MQ Explorer.

Comment: @NagendraBusam, you can stop the primary queue manager, just make sure that the option is specified to allow reconnectable clients to reconnect, from the command line this is accomplished by adding the `-r` flag to `endmqm`, so for example, instead of running `endmqm -i` you would run `endmqm -ir`.

Comment: MQConnectionFactory cf = (MQConnectionFactory) ff.createQueueConnectionFactory();  does this change look good? without this change I was not able add reconnect options.

Comment: I am a MQ admin primarily, but with that being said I think that change looks good.  As I said you can test it by stopping the queue manager to cause it to go into a reconnect cycle and then when you restart the queue manager it should reconnect, this is all silent to you, so if you see no error and you can put messages following the restart then everything is working.  If you have multi-instance then you could cause a switch the secondary server and then make sure it reconnects, as to how to do this I would need to look it up as I have not used MI much.