# Reusing JMSContext in IBM MQ

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, jmscontext

I'm trying to reuse a `JMSContext` to send multiple messages using the same context as shown in this [IBM MQ tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/slow-lost-messages-high-cpu-improve-your-mq-app/).

```
context = cf.createContext();
destination = context.createQueue(QUEUE_NAME);
producer = context.createProducer();

for (int i = 1; i <= 5000; i++) {
  try {
     TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage("Message " + i + ".\n");
     producer.send(destination, message);
  } catch (Exception ignore) {}
}
context.close();
```

Say the connection is dropped at some point. Will the context auto recovers or will I need to reconstruct the context again?

---

**UPDATE --**

This is how the current connection factory is being constructed:

```
JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

cf.setStringProperty    (CommonConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, config.getHost());
cf.setIntProperty       (CommonConstants.WMQ_PORT, config.getPort());
cf.setStringProperty    (CommonConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, config.getChannel());
cf.setIntProperty       (CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
cf.setStringProperty    (CommonConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, config.getQueueManager());
cf.setBooleanProperty   (JmsConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, false);
cf.setIntProperty       (JmsConstants.PRIORITY, 0);

return cf.createContext();
```

Comment: Depends on if you enable reconnect on the cf or not.

Comment: Check the bottom of my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56370312/ibm-mq-how-to-connect-to-queue-manager-with-multiple-connections-names-one-i/56370695#56370695

Comment: @JoshMc It seems to only work for multi host setup. I've a context made with single host. Can't seem to find a way to recover connection without reconstructing context?

Comment: Does "disconnected my connection" mean you pull the network connection?  For how long?

Comment: What exactly does "keep failing" mean.  What error and stack trace do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Reconnect works like this (see also comment of @JoshMc):

1. On the client, set the reconnect option like this:

   ```
   cf.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, CommonConstants.WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
   ```
2. On the server, stop the queue manager like this:

   ```
   endmqm -r
   ```

Comment: I have it set. I tried dropping the connection. And establishing it back. But then after if I try to send a messages using the same context it would keep failing.

Comment: How did you drop the connection?

Comment: I'm running the client locally. I just disconnected my connection, then reconnects it.

Comment: Does reconnect work when you stop the Queue Manager with `endmqm -r`?

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried with creating `JMSContext` from existing one?

```
JMSContext#createContext(int sessionMode)
```

It will create new `JMSContext` but reuse the same connection.

Reference:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/intro_jms_model.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/JMSContext.html